# Exposing error values to component in Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a component that uses redux form and validates like so:

```
const validate = values => {
  // Initialize errors constant.
  const errors = {};

  const testEmail = value =>
    value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) ?
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address' : undefined;

  // Only run test if email exists.
  testEmail(values.email);

  // Show error if value is touched and not filled out.
  const required = ['email', 'team', 'gameID', 'season', 'winner', 'bet', 'contractName'];
  required.map( input => {

    if (!values[input]) {
      return errors[input] = 'Required'
    };

    return null;
  });

  return errors;
}

const SportsFormWithCSS = CSSModules(SportsForm, styles, { allowMultiple: true });

SportsForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'SportsForm',
  validate
})(SportsFormWithCSS);
```

Is there a way I can add the error values to props, for instance? I have tried a couple implementations with little luck.

Comment: Why you need to add the errors to props? What is your use case or requirement? State that clearly.

Comment: Sure.

Essentially, the form is done in stages -- they want to confirm portions of the form as they go. (like split into 3rds -- and as they click a button, the CSS changes and it shows the next part of the form)

I'd love to do stuff like make the button disabled unless they had a valid entry for an email, for instance, without hacking in a ton of logic (if I need to do that, there's less point using the built in validation feature).